# Why doesn't this code color the background of the paragraph red?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why doesn't this code color the background of the paragraph red?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p  id="demo">Hi.</p>
    <script>
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your page does not import jQuery (which will provide `$()`)

Comment: If you add jQuery to the page it does.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no canonical dupe for this?

Comment: Unfortunately most issues caused by jQuery not being included are X/Y questions (exactly like this). As such I can't find a dupe target. I voted to close as a basic error/typo instead.

Answer (score -3):

You're trying to use jQuery when you haven't referenced it.
A pure JS solution is:

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

If you add jQuery to your page you can do:

```
$(function() {
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

And as some of the comments added, you don't need `document.ready` if you've placed all your scripts right before the `</body>` closing tag

Comment: document.ready is not needed in this example. There is a much bigger problem

Comment: You're 100% right @Rory McCrossan, just edited my response for future reference. Thank you